# What could cause quaternion error to go up drastically when a gyroscope is rotated on more than one axis at a time?

Tags: imu, gyroscope, rotation

Alright, I'm working on a small Arduino script that determines orientation using a a gyroscope and a quaternion. My hardware:

- LSM9DS1 IMU (Gyroscope, Accelerometer, Magnetometer)
- Teensy 4.0

My basic flow is:

1. Set gyroscope to measure -2000< x <2000 deg/s
2. Calibrate each axis by taking 1000 measurements and dividing the summed total of those measurements by the number of measurements taken to obtain the average value value. This value is then subtracted on each subsequent measurement of the gyroscope.
3. Calculate the change time differential of the quaternion
4. Propagate the previous quaternion using that time differential (ensuring that I normalize at each point to ensure the quaternion magnitude is always 1)

When rotating on a single axis at a time, the accuracy is pretty good. Even at high rotation rates, the values of the quaternion will return to their original, post-cal values.

BUT, when rotating on multiple axes at a time, the accuracy quickly deteriorates. Like picking up the board and moving it in whatever directions, then setting it back down in its (sort of) original position, the quaternion is absolutely all over the place.

I am fairly confident I've gotten the algorithm for calculating the quaternion correct. Looking at the calculated gyro values, they don't seem to be improperly scaled, clipped, or railing.

I am only using dead reckoning, understand that it can cause error, and know that I'll need to do some sort of correction if I want things to be really accurate. It just seems like somethings wrong. Or Im not understanding something about how the gyro works, or missing something about how error accumulates in the algorithm.

In general, is there something about multi-axis movement vs single axis movement that causes quaternion propagation to deteriorate so quickly?

Anyway, heres the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "SparkFunMPL3115A2.h"

#include <LSM9DS1_Registers.h>
#include <LSM9DS1_Types.h>
#include <SparkFunLSM9DS1.h>

// CHANGE TO ALLOW FOR VARYING LOOP SIZE

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// STATE LOOP DEFINITIONS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned long mission_time;
unsigned long flight_control_loop_delta = 50000;
unsigned long flight_control_loop_time = 0;
unsigned long flight_data_loop_delta = 10000;
unsigned long flight_data_loop_time = 0;
unsigned long flight_tx_loop_delta = 200000;
unsigned long flight_tx_loop_time = 0;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FLIGHT CONTROL DEFINITIONS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
boolean abort_mission = 0;
unsigned int current_state;
unsigned int queued_state;
const String possible_states[11] = {"ground_idle", // ---------- 1
                                    "pad", // ------------------ 2
                                    "abort", // ---------------- 3
                                    "powered_ascent", // ------- 4 
                                    "coast", // ---------------- 5
                                    "arcing_over", // ---------- 6 
                                    "drogue_deploy", // -------- 7
                                    "drogue_descent", // ------- 8
                                    "main_deploy", // ---------- 9
                                    "main_descent", // --------- 10
                                    "landed"}; // -------------- 11


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FLIGHT DATA DEFINITIONS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const float deg_to_rad = PI/180;
const int cal_reading_count = 1000;

float gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z;
float gyro_x_cal = 0, gyro_y_cal = 0, gyro_z_cal = 0;

float q [4] = {1, 0, 0, 0};
float omega [16] = {};
float q_dot [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// HARDWARE DEFINITIONS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int pin_green = 2, pin_red = 3, pin_blue = 4, pin_yellow = 5;
LSM9DS1 imu;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BEGIN SETUP
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // start serial at a high baud rate
  Wire.begin(); // turn on i2c

  imu.settings.device.commInterface = IMU_MODE_I2C;
  imu.settings.device.mAddress = 0x1E;
  imu.settings.device.agAddress = 0x6B;
  if (!imu.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to communicate with LSM9DS1.");
    Serial.println("Double-check wiring.");
    Serial.println("Default settings in this sketch will " \
                  "work for an out of the box LSM9DS1 " \
                  "Breakout, but may need to be modified " \
                  "if the board jumpers are.");
    while (1)
      ;
  }
  imu.setGyroScale(2000);
  
  queued_state = "ground_idle";
  current_state = 1;
  setup_sensors();
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BEGIN LOOP
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void loop() {

  // get the mission time at the front of the loop for comparison in the switch
  mission_time = micros();
  
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // BEGIN SWITCH
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  switch(current_state) {
    
    
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // GROUND STATE
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    case 1:
      // run the data loop to collect most recent flight data
      if (mission_time-flight_data_loop_time >= flight_data_loop_delta) {
//        Serial.print("Data loop: ");
        Serial.println(mission_time-flight_data_loop_time);
        flight_data_loop_time = mission_time;
        collect_sensor_data(flight_data_loop_time);
        calc_omega();
        calc_quart_dot();
        calc_orientation();
        print_quats();
//        print_gyro();
      }
    
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // UNDEFINED
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  } 
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup_sensors()
{
  calibrate_sensors();
}

void collect_sensor_data(long collection_time)
{



  imu.readGyro();
  gyro_x = (imu.calcGyro(imu.gx)-gyro_x_cal)*deg_to_rad;
  gyro_y = (imu.calcGyro(imu.gy)-gyro_y_cal)*deg_to_rad;
  gyro_z = (imu.calcGyro(imu.gz)-gyro_z_cal)*deg_to_rad;

  

  // if data_counter is less than the maximum, add data to the arrays
}

void calibrate_sensors() {
  for (int i = 0; i < cal_reading_count; i++) {
    delay(5);
    
   
    imu.readGyro();
    
    

    gyro_x_cal += imu.calcGyro(imu.gx);
    gyro_y_cal += imu.calcGyro(imu.gy);
    gyro_z_cal += imu.calcGyro(imu.gz);
  }
  

  gyro_x_cal = gyro_x_cal/float(cal_reading_count);
  gyro_y_cal = gyro_y_cal/float(cal_reading_count);
  gyro_z_cal = gyro_z_cal/float(cal_reading_count);
}

void calc_orientation()
{
  float delta = flight_data_loop_delta/1000000.0;
  q[0] += q_dot[0]*delta;
  q[1] += q_dot[1]*delta;
  q[2] += q_dot[2]*delta;
  q[3] += q_dot[3]*delta;

  float q_norm = sqrt(sqr(q[0])+sqr(q[1])+sqr(q[2])+sqr(q[3]));
  
  q[0] = q[0]/q_norm;
  q[1] = q[1]/q_norm;
  q[2] = q[2]/q_norm;
  q[3] = q[3]/q_norm;  
}

void calc_omega()
{
  omega [0] = 0;
  omega [1] = gyro_x;
  omega [2] = gyro_y;
  omega [3] = gyro_z;
  omega [4] = -gyro_x;
  omega [5] = 0;
  omega [6] = -gyro_z;
  omega [7] = gyro_y;
  omega [8] = -gyro_y;
  omega [9] = gyro_z;
  omega [10] = 0;
  omega [11] = -gyro_x;
  omega [12] = -gyro_z;
  omega [13] = -gyro_y;
  omega [14] = gyro_x;
  omega [15] = 0;
}

void calc_quart_dot()
{
  q_dot[0] = -.5*float(omega[0]*q[0] + omega[1]*q[1] + omega[2]*q[2] + omega[3]*q[3]);
  q_dot[1] = -.5*float(omega[4]*q[0] + omega[5]*q[1] + omega[6]*q[2] + omega[7]*q[3]);
  q_dot[2] = -.5*float(omega[8]*q[0] + omega[9]*q[1] + omega[10]*q[2] + omega[11]*q[3]);
  q_dot[3] = -.5*float(omega[12]*q[0] + omega[13]*q[1] + omega[14]*q[2] + omega[15]*q[3]);
}


float sqr(float num)
{
  return num*num;
}

void print_quats()
{
  Serial.print(q[0]);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(q[1]);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(q[2]);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(q[3]);
  Serial.println();
}

void print_gyro() {
  Serial.print(gyro_x);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(gyro_y);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(gyro_z);
}
```

Hope this is enough info to help out. Thanks!